# Is there R package or function used to convert similar strings to groups of substrings or regexps?

Tags: regex, string, r

I am trying to code function for machine conversion from character vector of labels to character vector of regexp subgroups, just like in the following example, where lab is the vector of labels and pat as mentioned obvious result characterizing the lab contents by regexp groups.

I started by comparison of strings with the same length, using adist functionality, but I think I am reinventing wheel.

Is there any existing package or function handling that? Or anything which is close enough to start with?

In real life my lab object may have length 1k - 5k and the particular label can contain any description. The one below is created as a showcase.

```
lab <- c(
"Speed - unit 1",
"Speed - unit 2",
"Speed - unit 3",
"Speed - unit 4",
"Speed - unit 5",
"Layer A",
"Layer B",
"Layer Cx",
"Colour Left",
"Colour Right",
"Colour Up",
"Colour Down"
)

pat <- c(
"^Speed - unit .$",
"^Layer [ABCx]*$",
"^Colour .*"
)
```

Comment: This is an open research question: see e.g. http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~fernau/papers/Fer05c.pdf

Comment: Thank you Hadley for pointing to the paper, it looks like it could be a real stumper.